# how to get justgetflux working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I installed justgetflux indicator applet in Ubuntu 14.04 but it doesn't work.

Are there any alternatives other than justgetflux for Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

**Redshift**

Redshift is a alternative to justgetflux. It also change desktop according to the climate.

```
sudo apt-get install redshift
```

[image: Install via the software center]

[image]

Comment: flux on windows is OK, but on ubuntu14 stopped work for me, so this is great alternative and even better because I can set more higher temperature brightness contract, thank you!

Comment: This even detects your location automatically, no need for looking up coordinates.