# Brightness Ubuntu vs. Kubuntu and Xubuntu

Tags: laptop, brightness, backlight

On Kubuntu and Xubuntu the brightness of my monitor goes down to zero (i.e. the backlight got switched off).

On Ubuntu this does not happen, the minimux brightness is still with backlight on and sometimes, especially at night, is too bright and painful.

Anyone that has some ideas on why is it and on how to allow Ubuntu to go down to 0?

[My hardware configuration](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12600549/)

Comment: It's not an answer just a work-around: Try redshitf: http://askubuntu.com/a/482596/428369 . if you are on 12.04 f.lux also helps to dim the screen https://justgetflux.com/

Comment: Do you know whether it works on Ubuntu? Because it does not show up... And for the brightness (option `-b N`), it overlaps a grey layer to the screen, it does not change the brightness :(

Comment: yeah, for me too it did not appear on applications menu, but it works from terminal: `redshift &`

Comment: I found [the indicator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gtk-redshift/)

Comment: Well, I'm using  gnome-fallback. Maybe that's why it does not show up for me.

Comment: Did you install it? Does it say anything when opened by terminal?

Comment: Yes, I installed it and worked from terminal. It does not return any message but dimmed the screen. you can kill the process anytime you like by `pkill redshift`.

Comment: If you want the icon, you have to launch `gtk-redshift` :)

Comment: No new on this anybody? :(

Comment: What Ubuntu Version are you on? After I upgraded to 15.X my monitor could go to zero brightness, but before it could not.

Comment: 15.10, but it was the same with older versions since I remember :)

Comment: @dadexix86, you may try this workaround  http://askubuntu.com/questions/632698/screen-brightness some thing like: `sudo sh -c "echo '0' >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"`

Comment: @Sneetsher That does the same as putting the brightness to 0 in Ubuntu, aka does not switch off the backlight...

Comment: @dadexix86, another try  `sudo sh -c "echo -n '4' >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/bl_power"` ref: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-class-backlight

Comment: @Sneetsher Nope, also the last does not change anything. BTW, since that is for HAL, I believe that that is why it does not work any more on Ubuntu ;)